# When I debug with Eclipse, why the size of the arraylist is 1 but the elementData is 10?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, arraylist

I want to solve this question
    1 -> A
    2 -> B
    3 -> C
    ...
    26 -> Z
    27 -> AA
    28 -> AB 
Here is my code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Solution {

    public static String convertToTitle(int n) {
        if(n<=0)
            return null;
        List temp=new ArrayList();

        int i=0;
        while(n!=0)
        {
            int residual=0;

            residual=n%26;
            n=n/26;
            temp.add((char)(residual-1+'A'));
            i++;
        }           
        char[] temp_final=new char[i];
        for(int j=0; j<i-1;j++)
            temp_final[j]=(char)(temp.remove(j));
        return String.valueOf(temp_final);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      String test;
      test=Solution.convertToTitle(2);
      System.out.println(test);
    }
}
```

The result is null. I do not know the reason. When I debug with Eclipse, I find the size of temp shows 1, but in the elementData  Object shows 10 elements.The first element is B, the other nine are null. Why is it 10 rather 1? Is it due to this? 
This the image of variables when debugging
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zN9ui.png)

Answer (score 1):

> Why is it 10 rather 1?

Because that is the way that `ArrayList` works!

An array list stores the list in a backing array (`elementData`).

When you create an `ArrayList` with `new ArrayList()`, the initial backing array size will be 10.  (Refer to the source code; e.g. [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.%3Cinit%3E%28%29).)

Why did they do this?

It is all about maintaining this guarantee stated in the javadoc:

> "As elements are added to an ArrayList, its capacity grows automatically. The details of the growth policy are not specified beyond the fact that **adding an element has constant amortized time cost**."

The way that this is achieved is to start the backing array with a reasonable "initial capacity", and grow the array exponentially when it fills up.  The exact details vary with Java version.

---

Hypothetically, the `ArrayList` class could use a backing array that is the same size as the list size.  But that gives terrible performance.  Each time you added an element to the list you would need to "grow" the backing array.  That entails allocating a new array with size 1 greater than the current size, and then copying the existing elements one at a time to the new array.  If you do the math, appending an element to a list of size `N` involves copying `N` existing element references ... making the append operation `O(N)`.

Answer (score 0):

An `ArrayList` is a `List` implementation using an array to store the elements.

At any point in time, a `List` has a `size()`, i.e. the number of elements in the list. For an `ArrayList`, those elements are stored in a single array with a `length` that is greater than or equal to the `size()` *(can't very well be less than `size()`, right?)*

The array `length` is called the *capacity* of the `ArrayList`, i.e. the number of elements the `ArrayList` can handle without having to re-size the array.

The debugger shows the `size` and the `elementData` array, but only the first `size` values of the array are "in the list".

By default, a new `ArrayList` has an *initial capacity* of 10. In Java 8, the backing array will be increased in size in 50% chunks when needed, i.e. 10, 15, 22, 33, 49, 73, 109, ...

If you know you're going to add 1000 elements to an `ArrayList`, you can specify the initial capacity on the [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-int-). That prevents the need for continually resizing the array as the 1000 elements are added (performance boost).